# How do I stream a video to an AV player in an iOS app?

Tags: ios, swift, video-streaming, avplayer

I am trying to make an app where a 360 video is played in VR format on the user's phone. I am using an AV player to display the video and it is all working when I have the video built into the app as a file. However, the video I actually want to be played is 30mins long and takes up about 5GB of storage which would be very inconvenient for a user to download. My solution to this would be to stream the video which can be stored in Dropbox, for example, so there is no need for the user to download it.

Here is my code for the AV player:

```
func addARTV() {
    fileURL = URL(fileURLWithPath:Bundle.main.path(forResource: "poolSession", ofType: "m4v")!)
    player = AVPlayer(url: fileURL!)
    
    let tvGeo = SCNSphere(radius:  10)
    tvGeo.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = player
    tvGeo.firstMaterial?.isDoubleSided = true
    
    tvNode = SCNNode(geometry: tvGeo)
    
    tvGeo.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contentsTransform = SCNMatrix4Translate(SCNMatrix4MakeScale(-1, 1, 1), 1, 0, 0)
    
    sceneView.scene.rootNode.addChildNode(tvNode)
    sceneView2.scene.rootNode.addChildNode(tvNode)
    
    player.play()
    isPlaying = true
}
```

I have spent weeks trying to research whether it is possible to stream a video to an app and if so how to do it but I have found no solutions that are working for me. I have also tried just changing the fileURL to the link to the file in Dropbox but nothing is working.

Comment: Always start with the Apple documentation Apple has a code sample for streaming

Comment: Could you possibly give me a link to it as I have just had a look and cant find it

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/offline_playback_and_storage/using_avfoundation_to_play_and_persist_http_live_streams